# A word for a statement that doesn't need to be said

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word with this definition:

"Something said or written that is so implied or self-evident that making the statement is completely unnecessary."

The closest word I can come up with is *truism*.

Comment: Could you please give an example sentence where you would like to use it? i.e. "He just always repeats ...."

Comment: As evidenced from the answers, and as is ubiquitous in English, context is going to be very important here. While the given answers are all generally valid, the answerers here are imagining each a different type of context for the words they've suggested. The ones which will apply to your use case will depend heavily upon what, precisely, that is.

Comment: ..*Derivative*.

Answer (score 14):

You should check [implicit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicit):

> understood though not clearly or directly stated

Common synonyms I saw in use are *tacit* and *unspoken*. They are listed along with the [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicit).

Comment: OTOH, something logically implicit may not be at all obvious.  "*capable of being understood from something else though unexpressed*" [-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicit), like a simpler mathematical proof discovered long after a lengthy one.

Answer (score 8):

Two words: 'a given'. Otherwise, 'self-evident' or 'obvious'.

For a younger audience: 'Duh'.

Comment: 'self-evident' is included in the question, and hence is clearly not an appropriate answer.

Comment: It is not self-evident that 'self-evident' is an appropriate adjective for the answer. 'Implied', for example, would not be satisfactory because it lacks strength.

Answer (score 7):

You may be looking for the word "superfluous". From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superfluous)

> 1
>          a :  exceeding what is sufficient or necessary :  extra
>          b :  not needed :  unnecessary

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest **redundant**.

As shown below, the definitions in both British & American English refer to using superfluous words.

> **redundant** ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/redundant))
>   *adjective*
>
> *British English:*
>   not needed
>   (especially of a word, phrase, etc.) unnecessary because it is more than is needed:
>   Example:
>   *In the sentence "She is a single unmarried woman", the word "unmarried" is redundant.*
>
> *American English:*
>   more than what is usual or necessary, esp. using extra words that mean the same thing:
>   Example:
>   *My English teacher was merciless if what we wrote was abstract, sentimental, or redundant.*

Although the example sentences above primarily relate to using more words that necessary, the simple definition of **redundant** is *not needed*. It can therefore equally be used to refer to an entire sentence or statement; for example:

> That statement is redundant.

Comment: Redundant is more about using (more) words than needed to express the sentiment; not about stating something that's already understood/known. As also illustrated in your linked example with the unmarried - single reference.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen See amended answer.

Comment: How does "She is a single unmarried woman" differ from "She is a single widowed woman" or "She is a single divorced woman".  The point here being that `single` is only borderline redundant here, and I would consider the AE example to be a use of the word without much context.  Some American examples: `absolutely phenomenal`, `completely unanimous`, `he\she is a person who`, `personal opinion`, I could go on.

Comment: @USER_8675309 They were the dictionary's examples - not mine.  I've merely put forward a suggested word & quoted its definition & example usage. I'm not saying they're the best examples - but I prefer to use properly substantiated examples where I can.

Comment: I find it ironic that a dictionary contains two definitions of "redundant" that are essentially identical.

Comment: @Jules It's not clear what you're referring to. Are you referring to the separate *British* & *American* definitions? If so, several dictionaries contain separate sections/definitions for British & American English (apparently so that either can stand alone). In some cases the definitions are *actually* identical - but how else do they ensure that they cover both BrE & AmE? People would find it unhelpful if say the AmE entries kept cross-referencing the BrE entries (which are on separate pages) or *vice versa*. I suggest you have a look at how the dictionaries are set out.

Comment: @Jules look at the definition of "Gullible", your picture is on it : ) TrevorD: you should look up the definition of 'joke', I think you need a refresher.

Answer (score 3):

**truism**

as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truism).

**obvious** and **implicit** are adjectives describing this.

**tautology** is sometimes wrongly used to describe this, as it means a statement that is true due to its form (a statement which is true independent from its interpretation).

**redundant** sounds quite technical, usually referring to the non-informative content of an information.

Answer (score 1):

[*axiomatic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axiomatic)

> obviously true
>
> taken for granted :  self-evident

Comment: I seriously wonder why I bother to contribute to this site. I linked to the dictionary even but nothing is ever good enough around here.

Comment: That comment was prompted by a downvote in case anybody wondered.

Comment: There's an unwanted connotation of condescension in *axiomatic*: we're probably all familiar with famous proofs and methods without knowing the proofs themselves -- a boy might be able to *use* the Pythagorean Theorem to estimate the size of a ladder needed to paint a 3rd floor window, *without* being able to prove it, i.e. he knows the proposition, *not* the axioms which precede it.  (Historically this is how a lot of Mathematics evolved: tradesmen and workers noticed various useful truths of measurement, which were later abstracted into the briefest possible axioms by leisurely scholars.)

Comment: @shawnt00, **axiomatic** means *taken for granted* and *self-evident*, but not *obviously true* - so it is not what the OP is looking for. Within a given theory, an axiom is a non-tautological statement which is supposed to be true. (Theological Sciences call it a **dogma**).

Comment: @rexkogitans As a mathematician myself I know what an axiom is. And while I prefer not to use the word in this sense, other people do use it more loosely. You can take that up with them and Merriam-Webster I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

"Something said or written that is so implied or self-evident that making the statement is completely unnecessary" that would be an **obvious** statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "tautology," although I admit it has some of the same problems as "redundant." Both have connotations of repetition that are missing in the poster's definition. "Superfluous" might be better, but its domain is not limited primarily to speech.

Another answer dismissed "tautology" as a possible answer to this question by arguing that the word's common meaning of redundancy is actually incorrect, and that the only correct definition of "tautology" is its technical definition in formal logic ("a statement that is true by necessity or by virtue of its logical form," to quote from the New Oxford American Dictionary -- a statement that by virtue of its logical structure is true in every possible state description within a given logical theory, e.g. "p or not p" in a binary logical system in which all statements are either true or false). But the more common definitions of "tautology" are listed alongside the formal logical definition of tautology in most dictionaries. To use "tautology" to mean a redundant phrase is only incorrect when a listener or writer would reasonably expect the word's technical definition to be employed. Many technical terms have vastly different lay meanings, but this generally does not make the lay meanings incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In the technical discussions, we say:

"That's *implied*."

> adjective: implied
>
> ```
> suggested but not directly expressed; implicit.
> ```

'stating the obvious
or something that does not need to be explicitly stated.'

Answer (score -1):

Does **Common knowledge** satisfy the idea? I.e., "knowledge that is known by everyone or nearly everyone, usually with reference to the community in which the term is used."

Def. from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge

Comment: Please quote from what you link to in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

A *Latin* loan phrase adopted in English usage:

> **sine qua non**
>
> Sine qua non (/ˌsaɪni kweɪ ˈnɒn/; Latin: [ˈsine kwaː ˈnoːn])[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_qua_non) or
>   *condicio sine qua non* (plural: *condiciones sine quibus non*) is an
>   indispensable and essential action, condition, or ingredient. It was
>   originally a Latin legal term for "[a condition] without which it
>   could not be", or "but for..." or "without which [there is] nothing".
>
> As a Latin term, it occurs in the work of Boethius, and originated in
>   Aristotelian expressions.[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_qua_non) In recent times, it has passed from a
>   merely legal usage to a more general usage in many languages,
>   including English, German, French, Italian, Spanish, etc.
>
> --[WP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_qua_non)

Comment: I don't think this has the right meaning. From what I understand, a "sine qua non" is something that is indispensable, but the question asks for a word to describe statements that are unnecessary.

Comment: @sumelic: Yeah, no... formally that's true, but the more common hyperbolic English usage is "something that goes without saying, as *if* it were a basic and necessary prerequisite", rather than an *actual* logical necessity.  Some dictionary sample usages show this, yet the definition writers haven't much noticed, i.e.: [*A perfect cake is the since qua non of a birthday party*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sine-qua-non)... (obviously one could stage a birthday party without any cake, e.g. by substituting some other [well-decorated dessert](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/birthday-dog)).

Answer (score -3):

**understatement** fits the bill.  For example:

*Your car rolls off cliff into ocean...*

Your friend: "At least you'll save on the car wash."

You: "That's an understatement."